# Django forms.DateInput validation

Tags: django, forms, validation, date

I'm using the following form field definitions,

```
start_date = django.forms.DateField(
        label=_("Start date"), 
        initial=timezone.now().date(), 
        widget=django.forms.DateInput(format = '%Y/%m/%d'))

end_date = django.forms.DateField(
        label=_("End date"), 
        initial=None, 
        required=False, 
        widget=django.forms.DateInput(format = '%Y/%m/%d'))
```

Since I set the initial for `start_date`, it shows up on the form with the default value, something like "2013/06/25".

If I just click on submit, it immediately tells me this error:

> Start date: Enter a valid date.

This is without me even doing anything! How is it that an initial value assigned by Forms according to the pre-defined format FAIL the validation ?!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `'%Y/%m/%d'` is not in the `DateField`'s `input_formats` list. You can try to add it like this:

```
start_date = django.forms.DateField(label=_("Start date"),
                                    initial=timezone.now().date(),
                                    input_formats=['%Y/%m/%d'],
                                    widget=django.forms.DateInput(format = '%Y/%m/%d'), input_formats=('%Y/%m/%d'))
end_date = django.forms.DateField(label=_("End date"), 
                                  initial=None,
                                  required=False, 
                                  input_formats=['%Y/%m/%d'],
                                  widget=django.forms.DateInput(format = '%Y/%m/%d'), input_formats=('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to set the formats is to use the settings `DATE_INPUT_FORMAT` and `DATE_FORMAT` in `settings.py`. You can also find the default formats in the docs: [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/)

Example for European date formats:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%d.%m.%Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d.%m.%Y', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y', '%d %b %Y',
                      '%d %b, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%d %B, %Y',
                      '%d %B %Y']
```

Hint: Make sure your `USE_L10N` setting does not overwrite your format inputs where you dont want that. More about it in the official docs.