# Django registration broke after i18n addition

Tags: python, django, django-registration, django-i18n

I recently added i18n and l10n to my Django application, but my registration broke. I have this:

> myApp/views.py

```
def register_user(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         print "Is valid"
         form.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/register_success/')
   args = {}
   args.update(csrf(request))
   args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
   print "Is invalid"
   return render_to_response('register.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

> register.html

```
{% extends 'login_base.html' %}

{% block content %}

 <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-5"> 
   <h1> Join Now</h1>
     <form method='POST' action="{% url 'register' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.errors %}
          <p style="color: red;">
             Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
           </p>
       {% endif %}

    <table>
         {{ form.as_p }}
    </table>
        <input type='Submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>
     </form>
 </div> 


{% endblock %}
```

> urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns


urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myApp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^auth/$', 'myApp.views.auth_view', name='auth'),
    url(r'^register/', 'myApp.views.register_user', name='register'),
    url(r'^register_success/', 'myApp.views.register_success', name='register_success'),   
)
```

[image: My form]

I've thrown some debug statements in my `views` which suggests the form is invalid, but it worked before I changed to add support for i18n. Has anyone run into this before?

Some of the changes I've tried to make are changing all `HttpResponseRedirect('/foo/')` to `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foo'))` and changing form actions from `action='/register/'` to `action="{% url 'register' %}"`.

Any help would be great. Please let me know if I've left out any important details.

I'm using Django 1.7.4.

Thanks,
erip

**EDIT**

In my registration form, I get the error "Introduzca una fecha válida." (Use a valid date).

My current date format is MM/DD/YYYY, but I'm using Spanish. What do I do? I've already determined the date format in my `forms`, below:

> forms.py

```
class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
    """
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'), 
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    USER_TYPE = (
    ('S', 'Student'),
    ('T', 'Teacher'),
    ('B', 'Student/Teacher'),
    )

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput,label="Email")
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'), label="Date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY)")
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, label="Gender")
    user_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=USER_TYPE, label="Type of user")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password (again)")

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['email', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'user_type', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean(self):
        """
        Verifies that the values entered into the password fields match

        NOTE: Errors here will appear in ``non_field_errors()`` because it applies to more than one field.
        """
        cleaned_data = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).clean()
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match. Please enter both fields again.")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    user.set_adult()
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Can you share the output of the debug which leads you to believe the Form is invalid? I usually throw {{ form.errors }} into the template to see what's going on.

Comment: See edit. There's no error thrown by the template, but I put a print statement in the view.

Comment: If the form is not valid, you're overwriting the context variable with a brand new form instance.... so you're losing the errors dict.

Comment: Use the browser dev tools to confirm the POST data is sending in the expected format.

Comment: Also... you're setting the format on the widget but that may not be supported by the field itself.... See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17300025/263421

Answer (score 1):

To follow up my last comment with some code... at least start with this:

```
def register_user(request):
   args = {}
   args.update(csrf(request))

   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         print "Is valid"
         form.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/register_success/')
      else:
         print "Is invalid"  
         args = {}
         args.update(csrf(request))
         args['form'] = form
   else:
       args = {}
       args.update(csrf(request))
       args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()

   return render_to_response('register.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm not proud of the conditional hierarchy / dup code but it ought to do the job.